# Random number generation on card and on terminal?

Tags: javacard, prng

I am implementing a mutual authentication and I was wondering about Random number generation

> RandomData rnd = RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
>   rnd.generateData(RP, (short) 0, (short) 16);

This works of course, but according to my specifications 
    (I am again referring to Cipurse) in order to do a three-way challenge-and-response I 
    need to have a Random Number Generator on the terminal and on the picc. This is confusing me, since I am only aware of this way to create random data (and would use this way of implementing it twice, once in the install-method, once in the relevant process-method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal, IFD, inspection system etc. all point to the same thing: the system sending the commands to the card. So if you would run a Java application with `javax.smartcardio` then you could use the Java Standard Edition `SecureRandom` class.